# Android AES-CBC decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt some files encrypted in Android AES for studying purposes.

Here is where do I start: (I changed some methods names from the obfuscated version to make it slightly more readable)

```
public class a {
  public static String encode(String paramString) {
    String str = null;
    try {
      byte[] arrayOfByte = encode(getRaw(), paramString.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception = null;
    } 
    if (exception != null)
      str = func1((byte[])exception); 
    return str;
  }
  
// func1 and func2 are only used for changing the Exception object. I don't think these are very important.
  private static String func1(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) {
    if (paramArrayOfbyte == null)
      return ""; 
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(paramArrayOfbyte.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < paramArrayOfbyte.length; i++)
      func2(stringBuffer, paramArrayOfbyte[i]); 
    return stringBuffer.toString();
  }
  
  private static void func2(StringBuffer paramStringBuffer, byte paramByte) {
    paramStringBuffer.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(paramByte >> 4 & 0xF)).append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(paramByte & 0xF));
  }
  
  private static byte[] getRaw() throws Exception {
    return KeyGen.generateKey(new byte[] { 
          33, 83, -50, -89, -84, -114, 80, 99, 10, 63, 
          22, -65, -11, 30, 101, -118 }); // this has 16 length. I guess that this is IV.
  }
  
  private static native byte[] getEncrypted(String paramString);
  
  private static byte[] encode(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(getKey()));
    return cipher.doFinal(clear);
  }
  
  public static String decode(String paramString) {
    try {
      return new String(decode(getRaw(), getEncrypted(paramString)));
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      return null;
    } 
  }
  
  private static byte[] getKey() {
    try {
      byte[] arrayOfByte = b.decode("IUQSvE6r1TfFPdPEjfklLw==".getBytes("UTF-8"), 2);
      // b.decode is a method as public static native byte[]. 
      if (arrayOfByte != null)
        return KeyGen.generateKey(arrayOfByte); 
    } catch (Exception exception) {}
    return new byte[16];
  }
  
  private static byte[] decode(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(getKey()));
    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
  }
}
```

```
public class KeyGen {
  private static native KeyInstance constructKey(String paramString);
  
  public static byte[] generateKey(byte[] maybeIV) {
    if (paramArrayOfbyte != null) {
      KeyInstance keyinstance = constructKey("QrMgt8GGYI6T52ZY5AnhtxkLzb8egpFn3j5JELI8H6wtACbUnZ5cc3aYTsTRbmkAkRJeYbtx92LPBWm7nBO9UIl7y5i5MQNmUZNf5QENurR5tGyo7yJ2G0MBjWvy6iAtlAbacKP0SwOUeUWx5dsBdyhxa7Id1APtybSdDgicBDuNjI0mlZFUzZSS9dmN8lBD0WTVOMz0pRZbR3cysomRXOO1ghqjJdTcyDIxzpNAEszN8RMGjrzyU7Hjbmwi6YNK"); // this has 256 length.
      if (keyinstance != null)
        return extractKey(maybeIV, keyinstance); 
    } 
    return null;
  }
  
  private static native byte[] extractKey(byte[] maybeIV, KeyInstance keyinstance);
  
  private static class KeyInstance {
    public int[] hash = new int[256];
    
    public int x;
    
    public int y;
    
    private a() {}
  }
}
```

I think the followings are suspicious, and I can use them as clues for getting Key:

```
  private static byte[] getRaw() throws Exception {
    return KeyGen.generateKey(new byte[] { 
          33, 83, -50, -89, -84, -114, 80, 99, 10, 63, 
          22, -65, -11, 30, 101, -118 }); // this has 16 length. I guess that this is IV.
  }

// ...
      byte[] arrayOfByte = b.decode("IUQSvE6r1TfFPdPEjfklLw==".getBytes("UTF-8"), 2);
// ...

KeyInstance keyinstance = constructKey("QrMgt8GGYI6T52ZY5AnhtxkLzb8egpFn3j5JELI8H6wtACbUnZ5cc3aYTsTRbmkAkRJeYbtx92LPBWm7nBO9UIl7y5i5MQNmUZNf5QENurR5tGyo7yJ2G0MBjWvy6iAtlAbacKP0SwOUeUWx5dsBdyhxa7Id1APtybSdDgicBDuNjI0mlZFUzZSS9dmN8lBD0WTVOMz0pRZbR3cysomRXOO1ghqjJdTcyDIxzpNAEszN8RMGjrzyU7Hjbmwi6YNK"); // this has 256 length.
```

Also, I noticed that every encrypted file starts with the common byte sequence "42 47 54 31 01 00 00 00".

1. Where do I go further given these clues?
2. How can I read the source declared as native in .jar files?

Comment: What is the source of this code? There are tons of good codes around here and there and you find one that uses keygen as IV generation, who do the hell call encryption as [encode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86177/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka: I think this code has been reverse engineered. The names of the methods and variables were chosen by the person using the reverse engineering tools, not the programmer. The comments were also likely added by the reverse engineer. And the encryption here is probably for obfuscation purposes, just to frustrate reverse engineering efforts.

Comment: The native code should also be in APK file. It won't be java.

Comment: There are a couple of native methods in there, and it's not obvious how the key is generated. You can try static analysis of the so file where those methods are defined or dynamic analysis of the APK as the data producing the key seem to be static. The so libs should be in /lib and you can analyse them with disassemblers/debuggers, but usually it's not that easy.

Comment: The "for studying purposes" part can be ignored. If you want to learn how AES works you don't grab a random file and try to decrypt; you may be trying forever without gaining any specific insight in how encryption / decryption works. The header reads "BGT1" in ASCII and is probably followed by a length indication in little endian or possibly additional versioning.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk That is a nice catch.